# Layout editor rendering error (Not rendering)

Tags: android, material-design, android-layout-editor

I have been trying to create a collapsing toolbar using AppBarLayout and collapsing toolbar.

Once the AppBarLayout component is being added to the project the layout editor doesn't render, I have noticed it with some other components as-well such as FAB but I could remove the FAB and add it once I finished creating the layout. the error is only in the rendering and when I run the app it works great.

I have tried creating a new project with the default Scrolling activity that contains an AppBarLayout and collapsing toolbar and still the layout did not render and it will only render after removing the AppBarLayout, removing and adding it might fix the problem temporary but after some builds or changes the problem returns and the layout doesn't render in the layout editor again.

I have tried to solve the issue by clicking on file -> invalidate cache. it has solved the problem for a few moments but after adding some constraints with constraints layout problem occurred again.

Some of the default scrolling activity content including the appbar layout and collapsing toolbar

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


The errors received:


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@466d8fa7
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor738.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1339)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1471)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer_Delegate.doFrame(Choreographer_Delegate.java:66)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:563)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

--------------------------------------------------

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1ff1f72c
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor738.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1339)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1471)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer_Delegate.doFrame(Choreographer_Delegate.java:66)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:563)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with material components 1.1.0-alphax and current stable Android Studio (in my case, 3.4.1). Try going back to version 1.0.0 or downloading Android Studio 3.5 Beta-x (mine is beta-04).

Answer (score 0):

I have temporary solved the issue by clicking on file -> invalidate cache. it has solved the problem for a few moments but after adding some constraints with constraints layout problem occurred again